# about MySQL index condition push down

Tags: mysql

Table structure definition

```
CREATE TABLE `user_cp` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cp_id` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'cpId 下划线分割',
  `intimacy` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '加了add_exp后的当前等级下的经验',
   `attenuation_utime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '扣减时间',
  `utime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '更新时间',
  `ctime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '时间',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cp_id_unique` (`cp_id`),
  KEY `idx_attenuationutime_utime_intimacy_cpid` (`attenuation_utime`,`utime`,`intimacy`,`cp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31988443 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SQL

```
EXPLAIN SELECT cp_id
FROM user_cp
WHERE utime < 1707912100
 AND attenuation_utime < 1708430500
 AND intimacy > 0
```

[image]

MySQL Server version:5.7.32

Why does this SQL not use index push down? thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html says:

> ICP is used for the `range`, `ref`, `eq_ref`, and `ref_or_null` access methods when there is a need to access full table rows.

and later:

> `EXPLAIN` output shows Using index condition in the `Extra` column when Index Condition Pushdown is used. It does not show `Using index` because that does not apply when full table rows must be read.

Your EXPLAIN shows `Using index` because the query is able to avoid reading the full table row.

In other words, `Using index` is mutually exclusive with `Using index condition`. No query will use both.